# How to process uploaded file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I am trying to process an XML file using Javascript.

```
xhttp.open("GET","exportproject.xml",false);
```

What I want to do is, let the user specify the file (instead of hard-coding it to exportproject.xml) using file uploader and then process the same using Javascript instead of sending it to the server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to take a look at the HTML5 FileReader API - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a solution that requires a modern browser (basically, ie 9+) you can use the html5 file API with a basic `<input type="file">`.

Take a look at [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) link, there are a number of excellent examples to get you started.

Answer (score -4):

Javascript cannot read a file from the client machine (where the browser runs). That would be a security violation. You will have to submit the file to server and process it.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to say that you violate less security submitting to the server than processing locally.